# Pyramid Request: UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, utf-8, pyramid

I'm working with Pyramid framework, trying to post UTF8 data to it. 
Here the exception I got. I'm not sure how to fix this issue. Any ideas why it happents?

```
mod_wsgi (pid=1389): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/user/transcriptions/pyramid.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/transcriptions/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 187, in __call__
response = self.handle_request(request)
File "/home/user/transcriptions/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/tweens.py", line 20, in excview_tween
response = handler(request)
File "/home/user/transcriptions/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.5-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 100, in tm_tween
response = handler(request)
File "/home/user/transcriptions/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 164, in handle_request
response = view_callable(context, request)
File "/home/user/transcriptions/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 333, in rendered_view
result = view(context, request)
File "/home/user/transcriptions/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 471, in _requestonly_view
response = view(request)
File "/home/user/transcriptions/transcriptions/frontend_views.py", line 179, in rpc_adduser
data = request.params
File "/home/user/transcriptions/lib/python2.7/site-packages/WebOb-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/webob/request.py", line 832, in params
params = NestedMultiDict(self.GET, self.POST)
File "/home/user/transcriptions/lib/python2.7/site-packages/WebOb-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/webob/request.py", line 783, in POST
vars = MultiDict.from_fieldstorage(fs)
File "/home/user/transcriptions/lib/python2.7/site-packages/WebOb-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/webob/multidict.py", line 74, in from_fieldstorage
obj.add(field.name, decode(field.value))
File "/home/user/transcriptions/lib/python2.7/site-packages/WebOb-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/webob/multidict.py", line 67, in <lambda>
decode = lambda b: b.decode('utf8')
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 6-8: invalid data
```

The string that it's choking on is "Venus\xe4gen".

I'm submitting the data from an HTML form defined with these attributes:

```
<form name="form_reg" id="formtrans" method="post" action="signup"
        content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: What are you trying to POST? Something in your form-encoded data is *not* UTF-8. Your `rpc_adduser` is trying to access the `request.params` multidict structure, triggering a decode of the form data and the decode fails.

Comment: I'm posting an HTML form. The charset for the HTML file with that form is UTF-8 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Have you inspected `request.body`? That contains the raw POST.

Comment: Wrap your `request.params` in a `try`/`except UnicodeDecodeError, e` and log the value of `e.object[:50]` (or print it to stderr, depending on your setup). That will give us some idea what the bad data is...

Comment: It brings me "Venus\xe4gen", in original it's "Venusvägen". Not sure what to do with this.

Comment: Just tried type(e.object) it shows "<type 'str'>"

Comment: You'll get an error whether the type is `str` or `unicode`, because the input to `codecs.utf_8_decode` is always expected to be a string containing UTF-8 encoding, and your input isn't. Since pyramid and WebOb are acting as if the encoding should always be UTF-8, I wonder if there's some misconfiguration somewhere outside of pyramid. Is this a regular HTML form POST you're dealing with?

Comment: @MuMind, yeah just a regular HTML form. I have tried to set up the charset for this form: `<form name="form_reg" id="formtrans" method="post" action="signup" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` but it didn't help

Comment: Does getting rid of the `content` attribute and adding `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to the form element fix it for you?

Comment: nope, it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: damn! really thought that would work

Comment: @Fabian: No, that's not unicode either. That's Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm close to opening a question for this, the unicode code point is U+00E4, (thus why I figured `\xe4` was unicode), my quick check was `'ä'.decode('utf-8')` results in `u'\xe4'` (correct imho), while `'ä'.decode('latin-1')` results in `u'\xc3\xa4'`. Shouldn't both decodes result in `u'\xe4'`? Is  there a quick explanation or shall I open a new question?

Comment: @Fabian: you are using a byte string literal, and the encoding of that string is determined by your editor (or the terminal if you use an interactive python prompt). It looks like you use a UTF-8 encoding to create the character. Read [this article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) to fully understand the difference between Unicode and encodings. I've answered loads of Unicode and encoding questions too, if you want to look through my answers on SO.

Comment: @MartijnPieters guess I'll have to read that _again_ ;)

Comment: @Fabian: Another one then: the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html). Just remember, in python 2, `''` is a byte string, `u''` is a unicode string. The first one is encoded data, the later has been decoded to Unicode. So the first one is just bytes, really, and thus `'ä'` could be any series of bytes depending on how the file was saved or what encoding your terminal is set to when you typed it in on the keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok guys, seems I have found the problem. The thing is that the form is based on the server with PHP. It uses cURL to post the data from one server to another. The second server has Pyramid app, which accepts the request. I have added iconv('ISO-8859-1','UTF-8',$fields_string) and this get it fixed

```
            $fields = $_REQUEST;

            foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
            rtrim($fields_string,'&');                
            //open connection
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
            $fields_string = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $fields_string);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
```

I'm not sure why PHP is acting like this, the $_REQUEST should be in UTF-8 as the page's charset (meta as well) is utf-8. I'm not a big fan of PHP though. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: So your client was not a browser but PHP, and you needed to explicitly post UTF-8, as it would otherwise use Latin-1.

Comment: not PHP but cURL. But yeah, it's my mistake, I didn't realise that the data gets posted with cURL

Comment: Whoa! That would have been helpful to mention before. I had guessed it was a problem outside of pyramid, but I don't think any of us would have guessed it was an issue in the PHP middleman you never mentioned. Yeah, encoding is really tricky to get right, particularly when you're chaining together so many technologies like this.

Comment: Anyways, +1 for posting the solution.